# SQL View Creation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

I have two tables

```
Table FOO 
FooUniqueID| Year| Name| Worth|
---------------------------
1           2008   Bob    23.00 
2           2009   Bob    40200

Table Bar 
BarUniqueID | Name | Value
-----------------------
 1aBc         Year   2009
```

I would like to create a view.
That will select everything from FOO where the Year is equal

```
select value from Bar where name = year
```

without using a sub query.

thank you

Comment: Sql Server 2008 is the enviroment

Comment: You are supposed to update your question and retag it, not add the update as comment

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227037/can-i-get-better-performance-using-a-join-or-using-exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  FooUniqueID, Year, Name, Worth
FROM
  FOO
JOIN
  BAR on FOO.Year = BAR.Value
WHERE
  BAR.Name = 'Year'
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of program is at work.  This would work for some SQL flavors, I believe.

```
select value from FOO, Bar where FOO.year = Bar.year
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create view baz as 
select f.FooUniqueID, f.Year, f.Name as FooName, f.Worth,
    b.BarUniqueID, b.Name as BarName, b.Value 
from foo f 
inner join bar b on f.Year = b.Value and b.name = 'Year'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much point creating a `VIEW` for this alone, it's a trivial join:

```
SELECT FOO.*
FROM Bar
JOIN FOO ON FOO.Year=Bar.Value
WHERE Bar.Name='Year';
```

Comment: The view contains much more data, but I limited the problem to the underlying issue. I need to create a view that grabs a config value from another table.

Comment: +1, that is still trivial, watch out for nesting too many views, performance will go down