# SQL query to retrieve last record from a linked table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I wrote a query to compare 2 columns in different tables (`TRELAY` VS `TUSERDEF8`). The query works great, except that it retrieves the top record in the `TUSERDEF8` table which has a many to one relationship to the `TRELAY` table.

The tables are linked by `TRELAY.ID = TUSERDEF8.N01`. I would like to retrieve the latest record from `TUSERDEF8` and compare that record with the `TRELAY` record. I plan to use the max value of the index column (`TUSERDEF8.ID`) to determine the latest record.

I am using SQL Server.

My code is below, but I'm not sure how to change the query to retrieve the last `TUSERDEF8` record. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    TRELAY.ID, TRELAY.S15, 
    TUSERDEF8.S04, TUSERDEF8.N01, TUSERDEF8.S06
FROM 
    TRELAY
INNER JOIN 
    TUSERDEF8 ON TRELAY.ID = TUSERDEF8.N01
WHERE 
    LEFT(TRELAY.S15, 1) <> LEFT(TUSERDEF8.S04, 1)
    AND NOT (TRELAY.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' AND
             TUSERDEF8.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' AND
             TUSERDEF8.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using an ID column to determine which row is "last" is a bad idea

Using cryptic table names like "TUSERDEF8" (how is it different from TUSERDEF7) is a very bad idea, along with completely cryptic column names like "S04".

Using prefixes like "T" for table is a bad idea - it should already be clear that it's a table.

Now that all of that is out of the way:

```
SELECT 
    R.ID,
    R.S15,
    U.S04,
    U.N01,
    U.S06
FROM 
    TRELAY R
INNER JOIN TUSERDEF8 U ON U.N01 = R.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TUSERDEF8 U2 ON
    U2.N01 = R.ID AND
    U2.ID > U.ID
WHERE
    U2.ID IS NULL AND    -- This will only happen if the LEFT OUTER JOIN above found no match, meaning that the row in U has the highest ID value of all matches
    LEFT(R.S15, 1) <> LEFT(U.S04, 1) AND
    NOT (
        R.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' AND
        U.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' AND
        U.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%'
    )
```

Comment: Uncredited duplicate of the logic in this answer:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/2111420/1507566

Comment: It's "uncredited" because I just came up with the query myself. I don't scour the internet every time I type a query just to see if someone else might have typed it before. Do you give credit every time you write out a `WHILE` loop because someone once used one before you?

Comment: Only commenting to give the reason for my downvote, not meant to be a personal criticism, and I certainly didn't mean to imply that you were deliberately plagiarising.  I try not to downvote without a comment.   Thank you for voting to close.

Comment: BTW, here's my use of the same method a year and a half before Bill Karwin posted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227037/can-i-get-better-performance-using-a-join-or-using-exists/227363#227363. You should go down-vote him.

Comment: Sure about that link?   The answer I see seems to be about performance of JOINs vs EXISTS, which isn't the same thing at all.   But if you did post this logic earlier than the answer I cited, I'd be happy to favorite it for future flagging.  If you knew you'd already posted this logic, why not flag the dupe rather than answer?

Comment: Tom H., I didn't create the database. The tables, structure, etc. are from a COTS product. I do thank you for the help with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your expected output is still a little ambiguous.

It sounds to me like you want only the record from the output where TUSERDEF8.ID is at its max.  If that's correct, then try this:

```
SELECT TRELAY.ID, TRELAY.S15, TUSERDEF8.S04, TUSERDEF8.N01, TUSERDEF8.S06
FROM TRELAY
  INNER JOIN TUSERDEF8 ON TRELAY.ID = TUSERDEF8.N01
WHERE LEFT(TRELAY.S15, 1) <> LEFT(TUSERDEF8.S04, 1)
  AND NOT (TRELAY.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' AND
           TUSERDEF8.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' AND
           TUSERDEF8.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%')
  AND TUSERDEF8.ID IN (SELECT MAX(TUSERDEF8.ID) FROM TUSERDEF8)
```

EDIT: After reviewing your recent comments, it would seem something like this would be more suitable:

```
SELECT 
  , C.ID
  , C.S15, 
  , D.S04
  , D.N01
  , D.S06
FROM (
    SELECT A.ID, A.S15, MAX(B.ID) AS MaxID
    FROM TRELAY AS A
    INNER JOIN TUSERDEF8 AS B ON A.ID = B.N01
    WHERE 
    LEFT(A.S15, 1) <> LEFT(B.S04, 1)
    AND NOT (A.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' AND
             B.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' AND
             B.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%')
    GROUP BY A.ID, A.S15
) AS C
INNER JOIN TUSERDEF8 AS D ON C.ID = D.N01 AND C.MaxID = D.ID
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work for what I need, but what do you mean by the output is ambiguous?

Comment: @JoeChristou I mean that I'm not sure if you're asking for a 1-row output or something else (e.g., see the confusion in @Dave 's answer's comments).  The query I've provided will give you 1 row as your output where `TUSERDEF8.ID` is at its current maximum (i.e., if that ID doesn't have the appropriate relation built in `TRELAY` yet, then you'll get a 0-row answer).  This assumes an integer-based increasing `TUSERDEF8.ID`.  If you need 1 row every time you run the query, then you should go with @Dave's answer, as it will give you the latest `TUSERDEF8.ID` that has all of the relations already.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I want to cycle through all of the TRELAY records and do a comparison with the associated latest TUSERDEF8 record. To give a little background, we are doing a pre-assessment on each device to determine impact level, Low, Medium or No. then doing the official assessment in a different database. Those results are sent back to TUSERDEF8 and I want to do a comparison on the latest assessment (TUSERDEF8) to verify that the impact levels match. Hope that explains things.

Comment: To add to that, after re-reading the responses. I want the Max(TUSERDEF8.ID) from only the TUSERDEF8 records linked with each TRELAY.ID. God, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @JoeChristou So you want a multi-record output where each `TRELAY` record is matched only with its (maximum) `TUSERDEF8.ID` record?  I'll have to write up a different answer if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. Tom's answer below appears to work for me. I really appreciate the help. I struggled with this for a while.

Comment: @JoeChristou Tom's answer is fun (I've never used an `outer join U2.ID > U.ID` - like logic before).  I'm curious if it would execute faster than my answer or not.  Either way, you should mark one as 'correct'.

Comment: Thank you. I did mark Tom's answer correct since I was able to follow his code, but I really appreciate your help as well. I will definitely look over your code to make sure I understand it as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that your IDs are int(s) then the below might work?

```
SELECT TOP 1 TRELAY.ID, TRELAY.S15, TUSERDEF8.S04, TUSERDEF8.N01, TUSERDEF8.S06
FROM TRELAY INNER JOIN TUSERDEF8 
ON TRELAY.ID = TUSERDEF8.N01
WHERE LEFT(TRELAY.S15, 1) <> LEFT(TUSERDEF8.S04, 1)
AND NOT (
    TRELAY.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' 
    AND TUSERDEF8.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' 
    AND TUSERDEF8.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%'
    )
ORDER BY TUSERDEF8.ID DESC
```

HTH

Dave

Comment: This is only going to give one row, not the top row for each `TRELAY` row.

Comment: OK...didn't get the need for each row...think Joe C's CTE is probably the way to go...

Comment: I'm not sure how your query returned a "Low" in the TRELAY.S15 field.

Comment: @Joe Christou The question stated "...I would like to retrieve the latest record from TUSERDEF8 ..." and thus the "ORDER BY TUSERDEF8.ID DESC"..max id would be listed first that matched the TRELAY record. I did fully realize the requirement to find each TRELAY record that has a matching maximum TUSERDEF8 record...apologies...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
With cteLastRecord As
(
Select  S04, N01, S06, 
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By N01, Order By ID Desc) SortOrder 
    From TUSERDEF8
)
SELECT 
    TRELAY.ID, TRELAY.S15, 
    TUSERDEF8.S04, TUSERDEF8.N01, TUSERDEF8.S06
FROM 
    TRELAY
INNER JOIN 
    (Select S04, N01, S06 From cteLastRecord Where SortOrder = 1) TUSERDEF8 ON TRELAY.ID = TUSERDEF8.N01
WHERE 
    LEFT(TRELAY.S15, 1) <> LEFT(TUSERDEF8.S04, 1)
    AND NOT (TRELAY.S15 LIKE '%MEDIUM%' AND
             TUSERDEF8.S04 LIKE '%N/A%' AND
             TUSERDEF8.S06 LIKE '%EACMS%')
```