# Counting records based on conditions over potential null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, conditional-aggregation

I have this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_orders (
  "order_id" INTEGER,
  "customer_id" INTEGER,
  "pizza_id" INTEGER,
  "exclusions" VARCHAR(4),
  "extras" VARCHAR(4),
  "order_time" TIMESTAMP
);
INSERT INTO customer_orders
  ("order_id", "customer_id", "pizza_id", "exclusions", "extras", "order_time")
VALUES
  ('1', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 18:05:02'),
  ('2', '101', '1', '', '', '2020-01-01 19:00:52'),
  ('3', '102', '1', '', '', '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
  ('3', '102', '2', '', NULL, '2020-01-02 23:51:23'),
  ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
  ('4', '103', '1', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
  ('4', '103', '2', '4', '', '2020-01-04 13:23:46'),
  ('5', '104', '1', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:00:29'),
  ('6', '101', '2', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-08 21:03:13'),
  ('7', '105', '2', NULL, '1', '2020-01-08 21:20:29'),
  ('8', '102', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-09 23:54:33'),
  ('9', '103', '1', '4', '1, 5', '2020-01-10 11:22:59'),
  ('10', '104', '1', NULL, NULL, '2020-01-11 18:34:49'),
  ('10', '104', '1', '2, 6', '1, 4', '2020-01-11 18:34:49');

CREATE TABLE runner_orders (
  "order_id" INTEGER,
  "runner_id" INTEGER,
  "pickup_time" VARCHAR(19),
  "distance" DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
  "duration" VARCHAR(10),
  "cancellation" VARCHAR(23)
);
INSERT INTO runner_orders
  ("order_id", "runner_id", "pickup_time", "distance", "duration", "cancellation")
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2020-01-01 18:15:34', '20', '32', ''),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-01 19:10:54', '20', '27', ''),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-03 00:12:37', '13.4', '20', NULL),
  ('4', '2', '2020-01-04 13:53:03', '23.4', '40', NULL),
  ('5', '3', '2020-01-08 21:10:57', '10', '15', NULL),
  ('6', '3', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Restaurant Cancellation'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-08 21:30:45', '25', '25mins', NULL),
  ('8', '2', '2020-01-10 00:15:02', '23.4', '15', NULL),
  ('9', '2', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Customer Cancellation'),
  ('10', '1', '2020-01-11 18:50:20', '10', '10', NULL);
```

And I they gave me the question: For each customer, how many delivered pizzas had at least 1 change and how many had no changes?

Now, I tried to do this:

```
WITH cte_1
AS (
    SELECT co.customer_id
        , co.order_id
        , co.exclusions
        , isnull(co.exclusions,'') AS exc
        , isnull(co.extras,'') AS ext
    FROM customer_orders as co
    INNER JOIN runner_orders as ru 
        ON co.order_id = ru.order_id
    WHERE NOT ru.cancellation IN ('Restaurant Cancellation', 'Customer Cancellation')    
)    
SELECT customer_id
    , COUNT(order_id) AS no_changes 
FROM cte_1
WHERE exc = '' AND ext = ''
GROUP BY customer_id
```

As you can see this so long but at least works and the numbers are correct. But then when I try to do the same to get the result for pizzas with changes like this:

```
WITH cte_1
AS (
    SELECT co.customer_id
        , co.order_id
        , co.exclusions
        , isnull(co.exclusions,'') AS exc
        , isnull(co.extras,'') AS ext
    FROM customer_orders as co
    INNER JOIN runner_orders as ru 
        ON co.order_id = ru.order_id
    WHERE NOT ru.cancellation IN ('Restaurant Cancellation', 'Customer Cancellation')    
)    
SELECT customer_id
    , COUNT(order_id) AS with_changes 
FROM cte_1
WHERE not exc = '' 
GROUP BY customer_id
UNION
SELECT customer_id
    , COUNT(order_id) AS with_changes 
FROM cte_1
WHERE not ext = '' 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

It doesn't work, and I'm not sure if it's because of the Nulls and blanks or the approach in general. Please if there is a better and shorter way to do this.

EXPECTED RESULT  would be something like:

| customer_id | orders_with_changes | orders_with_NO_changes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | --- | 2 |
| 102 | --- | 3 |
| 103 | 3 | --- |
| 104 | 2 | 1 |
| 105 | 1 | --- |

Comment: Can you update your post with the full expected output?

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't a helpful problem statement. *Why* doesn't it work?

Comment: @lemon sure! Let me write it down and I'll update the post.

Comment: @ThomA Hi nice to see you again Tom, you helped me before haha and yeah is like you say, I want to know Why it doesnt work so I can learn and fix it.

Comment: @lemon done, that would be the expected result. Remeber order 6 and 9 wont count because, in the runners_orders table it says they were canceled.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid SQL Server syntax - are you sure that is what you are using?

Comment: And you almost certainly don't want `UNION` but want `UNION ALL` because `UNION` tries to de-dup the results and doesn't tend to perform too well.

Comment: @DaleK You mean because of the tables or what I tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: Well try and run your complete example in sql server and you'll see it doesn't run

Comment: As an example https://dbfiddle.uk/JNIZ95LE

Comment: @DaleK I see, that's weird because it works on my computer :/ Maybe If you change the TIMESTAMP for DATETIME? I did that but afer I created the table, part of the practice was to clean the data (there was some 'null' that I changed for NULL too) Here is the original table maybe you can spot what is wrong, I am new and when something goes wrong honestly I just panic haha  8weeksqlchallenge.com/case-study-2/   And please let me know what is wrong so I can learn and fix it here in my post :)

Comment: If it works on your computer then you aren't using SQL server.

Comment: @DaleK oh? yes I am, I installed it and I use it everyday :)  Maybe is your computer? Because Lemon didn't have problems with the table

Comment: SQL server does not support a `timestamp` which contains a datetime value. If you look at Lemons fiddle, they changed your `timestamp` to `datetime` which is the SQL Server datetime format. If you open the exercise you are working on in the provided fiddle it tells you clearly that its running on PostgreSQL which does support a `timestamp` datatype which takes a datetime value. If that fiddle works on your computer then you must also be running PostgreSQL - else it would give you an error.

Comment: @DaleK oh I see, thats why in my computer it also appears as datetime! I thought I changed it after creating the table,I probably changed it while creating the table then! I started this practice case a week ago so I didnt remeber that. sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try approaching this problem by:

- filtering on the runners table with the `NOT EXISTS` operator, to check and discard the orders that were subject to alteration by third-party, before any aggregation is carried out
- applying conditional aggregation with `COUNT` + `CASE` expression, by counting records that satisfy conditions (orders without changes are the ones that have both extras and exclusions null, while order with changes are identified by the opposite condition)

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT COALESCE(extras, '') = '' 
                    OR NOT COALESCE(exclusions, '') = '' THEN 1 END) AS num_with_changes,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(extras, '') = ''
                   AND COALESCE(exclusions, '') = '' THEN 1 END) AS num_with_no_changes
FROM customer_orders co
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM runner_orders ro 
                 WHERE co.order_id = ro.order_id 
                   AND NOT COALESCE(cancellation, '') = '')
GROUP BY customer_id
```

**Output**:

| customer_id | num_with_changes | num_with_no_changes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | 2 |
| 102 | 0 | 3 |
| 103 | 3 | 0 |
| 104 | 2 | 1 |
| 105 | 1 | 0 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MkdOwvCp).

Comment: wow thank you!. Well I need to look up the NOT EXISTS operator because I have not see it before and is blowing my mind that you dont need a JOIN to join the runners table, haha.

Comment: also this morning I tried and failed to use  COUNT + CASE, but using ISNULL  and got an error, haha Honestly I need to study CASE more I rarely get it right.  Thank you again I'll sit down and see if I understand everything here

Comment: It's actually doing a join operation under the hood, as the condition is applied inside the subquery (`co.order_id = ro.order_id`), although there *may be* [some efficiency differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227037/can-i-get-better-performance-using-a-join-or-using-exists). Usually I use `EXISTS` when I don't need to gather every column from the other table, but just check for specific conditions.

Comment: I see. And I have 2 minor questions. With COALESCE  I knew that it ended with the parentesis () why do you add  = ''  after that at the end? / And my other question is, in the subquery why do write SELECT 1 ? Because 1 is not a column

Comment: `COALESCE` takes the first non-null column. In our case we have say `COALESCE(extras, '')`. So it will first check if extras is NULL: if it's not null, will take its value, otherwise will go on and check if '' is NULL (which never happens). At the end of the day that expression will convert all NULL values to '', so that the check can either contain '' or a value that indicates a change.

Comment: Concerning `SELECT 1`, the DBMS is returning exactly the value 1 if the condition is satisfied, or NULL otherwise. We could have written `SELECT 0`, `SELECT 1`, `SELECT extras`, and would have been just fine, because we're only checking the existence of any value that satisfy a condition (or its non-existence). Using an integer is just a simplification, as long as it's a value we don't really care about, unless it's NULL.

Comment: I see I see the COALESCE is starting to make sense. The second one I need to google it a bit to fully get it,  that is quite new for me haha Thank you again!